# How to get SelectedItem of ComboBox as string which is inside DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `DataTemplate` containing a `ComboBox` which gets populated from the model I have. I've been trying to get the `SelectedText` of `ComboBox` but failed. tried almost everything mentioned in other answers.

This is my XAML code:

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="myTemplate">
    <ComboBox x:Name="ActionCombo" SelectedIndex="{Binding ActionId, Mode=TwoWay}" IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
              IsEditable="True" Text="Select Action" SelectionChanged="ActionCombo_SelectionChanged" 
              Initialized="ActionCombo_Initialized" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="Action"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

And this is model:

```
class Actions
{
     public int ID { get; set; }
     public string Action { get; set; }
}

actions.Add(new Actions() { ID= 0, Action="Issued" });
actions.Add(new Actions() { ID = 1, Action = "Resolved" });
actions.Add(new Actions() { ID = 2, Action = "Pending" });
```

these three items populate the `ComboBox` on `page_Load`.

Methods I tried on `Selection_Changed` event:

```
string txt = (((sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem) as ComboBoxItem).Name.ToString();
```

> Result=Null

```
string txt = (((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem).ToString();
```

> Result="WPFSample1App.Actions"

```
string txt = (((ComboBox)sender).Text);
```

> Result = "Select Action"

It always gets `SelectedItem` as `Action` Model(Which I don't want).
What to do?

**Edit:**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="strGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" SelectedIndex="0">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}" Width="25"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Store" Binding="{Binding StoreName}" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="TimeIn" Binding="{Binding TimeIn}" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="TimeOut" Binding="{Binding TimeOut}" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Action" Width="*" x:Name="comboTemp">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Name="myTemplate">
                    <ComboBox x:Name="ActionCombo" SelectedIndex="{Binding ActionId, Mode=TwoWay}" IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
                             IsEditable="True" Text="Select Action" SelectionChanged="ActionCombo_SelectionChanged" 
                             Initialized="ActionCombo_Initialized" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="Action">
                       <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding Action}"/>
                    </ComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Each `ComboBox` gets populated on Initialized event

```
private void ActionCombo_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ComboBox combo = sender as ComboBox;
     combo.ItemsSource = actions;
}
```

And the `DataGrid` gets populated on `page_load` with different source(database)

Comment: What hinders you from using `(((sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem) as Actions).Action`?

Comment: I don't want that, i need the text on it, because my goals is something like when there is more than one combobox present and when user doesn't select anything it should get "Select Action" which is not present in Actions Model.

Answer (score 1):

Your second approach is very close, try this

```
string txt = (((sender as ComboBox)?.SelectedItem) as Actions)?.Action?.ToString();
```

if the text was null then you could do something like this

```
if(txt == null)
{
     txt = (sender as ComboBox).Text;
}
```

Please note I havent tested it but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: What if User doesn't select anything, Then suppose on Submit button it should come as 'Select Action' but it isn't present in the Actions Model.

Comment: I don't know how you dealing with it in your app and your scenario. But if it was on any form with save button, I would keep the button disabled untill something was selected, on top of that I would indicate that this is a required field.

Comment: yes that thought has crossed my mind, but I'm not yet performing any validations. i just wanted to know if its possible.

Comment: @AwaisShaikh see my updated answer, so if there was no text after getting the selected item, then you get the text directly from combobox. If you want to keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Name` use `Content` like this:

```
string txt = (((sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem) as ComboBoxItem).Content.ToString();
```

Also you have missed `ComboBoxItem` in your XAML. It should be like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ActionCombo" SelectedIndex="{Binding ActionId, Mode=TwoWay}" IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
        IsEditable="True" Text="Select Action" SelectionChanged="ActionCombo_SelectionChanged" 
        Initialized="ActionCombo_Initialized" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="Action">
      <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding Action}"></ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

---

If you don't use `<ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding Action}"/>` you should get the result with following code:

```
string txt = (((sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem) as Actions).Action; .
```